# Option text position

Tags: css

Hi how i can change my text in option to a bit higher using css as is not in centre line

```
<div class="form-row">

                                    <div class="col">
                                      <label for="select-price-mode" class="col-form-label">Price Mode</label> 
                                      <select class="select-price-mode custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-price-mode"  required>
                                        <option selected disabled value="" >Select ....</option>
                                      </select>
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Please select a valid price mode.
                                      </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col">
                                        <label for="select-payment-frequency" class="col-form-label">Payment Frequency</label> 
                                        <select class="select-payment-frequency custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-payment-frequency" required>
                                          <option selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            Please select a valid payment frequency.
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
select{font-size: 30px;}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">

                                    <div class="col">
                                      <label for="select-price-mode" class="col-form-label">Price Mode</label> 
                                      <select class="select-price-mode custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-price-mode"  required>
                                        <option selected disabled value="" >Select ....</option>
                                      </select>
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Please select a valid price mode.
                                      </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col">
                                        <label for="select-payment-frequency" class="col-form-label">Payment Frequency</label> 
                                        <select class="select-payment-frequency custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-payment-frequency" required>
                                          <option selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                            Please select a valid payment frequency.
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks it work i realize all i do is css using my selected id for it